# keyboard behaves differently under bash

Tags: command-line, bash, keyboard, remote-access

When logged to other computer from windows under `bash`, putty maps keys properly but under other shells like `sh` or `zsh` keys like <kbd>Delete</kbd> are mapped incorrectly (to `~` character).

Setting `XTERM` to different maps does not change anything. My current `linux` map seems to be correct (delete key function `kdch1` is mapped to `\E[3~` and `cat` outputs `^[[3~`).

Why changing shells has this strange effect? Maybe this keymap is actually not used and there are newer mechanisms?

I have no ~/.inputrc, /etc/inputrc has following content:

```
# do not bell on tab-completion
#set bell-style none

set meta-flag on
set input-meta on
set convert-meta off
set output-meta on

# Completed names which are symbolic links to
# directories have a slash appended.
set mark-symlinked-directories on

$if mode=emacs

# for linux console and RH/Debian xterm
"\e[1~": beginning-of-line
"\e[4~": end-of-line
"\e[5~": beginning-of-history
"\e[6~": end-of-history
"\e[3~": delete-char
"\e[2~": quoted-insert
"\e[5C": forward-word
"\e[5D": backward-word
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word

# for rxvt
"\e[8~": end-of-line

# for non RH/Debian xterm, can't hurt for RH/DEbian xterm
"\eOH": beginning-of-line
"\eOF": end-of-line

# for freebsd console
"\e[H": beginning-of-line
"\e[F": end-of-line
$endif
```

Comment: Have you tried to fiddle with the `TERM` variable?

Comment: What is the output of `cat /etc/inputrc` and `cat ~/.inputrc`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bash` uses the `GNU readline` library to provide editing feature. You can see the difference if you launch a `bash` shell without readline support from your terminal with:

```
bash --noediting
```

It will behave exactly the same as `sh` (`dash`) or as your current `zsh`.

Zsh does not use `readline` (it does not read `inputrc`), but it has editing feature too, which for me was set up correctly when I choose the default setting when launched `zsh` for the first time. It gets the keybindings from the system-wide configuration file from `/etc/zsh/zshrc`. If you don't have that file or it doesn't set up keybindings then it is your job to set it up in your `~/.zshrc`, with the `bindkey`, like it is written [here](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide04.html). Or just get a proper system-wide zshrc file. Mine looks like this

```
# /etc/zsh/zshrc: system-wide .zshrc file for zsh(1).
#
# This file is sourced only for interactive shells. It
# should contain commands to set up aliases, functions,
# options, key bindings, etc.
#
# Global Order: zshenv, zprofile, zshrc, zlogin

READNULLCMD=${PAGER:-/usr/bin/pager}

if [[ "$TERM" != emacs ]]; then
[[ -z "$terminfo[kdch1]" ]] || bindkey -M emacs "$terminfo[kdch1]" delete-char
[[ -z "$terminfo[khome]" ]] || bindkey -M emacs "$terminfo[khome]" beginning-of-line
[[ -z "$terminfo[kend]" ]] || bindkey -M emacs "$terminfo[kend]" end-of-line
[[ -z "$terminfo[kich1]" ]] || bindkey -M emacs "$terminfo[kich1]" overwrite-mode
[[ -z "$terminfo[kdch1]" ]] || bindkey -M vicmd "$terminfo[kdch1]" vi-delete-char
[[ -z "$terminfo[khome]" ]] || bindkey -M vicmd "$terminfo[khome]" vi-beginning-of-line
[[ -z "$terminfo[kend]" ]] || bindkey -M vicmd "$terminfo[kend]" vi-end-of-line
[[ -z "$terminfo[kich1]" ]] || bindkey -M vicmd "$terminfo[kich1]" overwrite-mode

[[ -z "$terminfo[cuu1]" ]] || bindkey -M viins "$terminfo[cuu1]" vi-up-line-or-history
[[ -z "$terminfo[cuf1]" ]] || bindkey -M viins "$terminfo[cuf1]" vi-forward-char
[[ -z "$terminfo[kcuu1]" ]] || bindkey -M viins "$terminfo[kcuu1]" vi-up-line-or-history
[[ -z "$terminfo[kcud1]" ]] || bindkey -M viins "$terminfo[kcud1]" vi-down-line-or-history
[[ -z "$terminfo[kcuf1]" ]] || bindkey -M viins "$terminfo[kcuf1]" vi-forward-char
[[ -z "$terminfo[kcub1]" ]] || bindkey -M viins "$terminfo[kcub1]" vi-backward-char

# ncurses fogyatekos
[[ "$terminfo[kcuu1]" == "O"* ]] && bindkey -M viins "${terminfo[kcuu1]/O/[}" vi-up-line-or-history
[[ "$terminfo[kcud1]" == "O"* ]] && bindkey -M viins "${terminfo[kcud1]/O/[}" vi-down-line-or-history
[[ "$terminfo[kcuf1]" == "O"* ]] && bindkey -M viins "${terminfo[kcuf1]/O/[}" vi-forward-char
[[ "$terminfo[kcub1]" == "O"* ]] && bindkey -M viins "${terminfo[kcub1]/O/[}" vi-backward-char
[[ "$terminfo[khome]" == "O"* ]] && bindkey -M viins "${terminfo[khome]/O/[}" beginning-of-line
[[ "$terminfo[kend]" == "O"* ]] && bindkey -M viins "${terminfo[kend]/O/[}" end-of-line
[[ "$terminfo[khome]" == "O"* ]] && bindkey -M emacs "${terminfo[khome]/O/[}" beginning-of-line
[[ "$terminfo[kend]" == "O"* ]] && bindkey -M emacs "${terminfo[kend]/O/[}" end-of-line
fi

zstyle ':completion:*:sudo:*' command-path /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/bin \
                 /usr/sbin /usr/bin /sbin /bin /usr/X11R6/bin

unalias run-help
autoload run-help

# If you don't want compinit called here, place the line
# skip_global_compinit=1
# in your $ZDOTDIR/.zshenv or $ZDOTDIR/.zprofice
if [[ -z "$skip_global_compinit" ]]; then
  autoload -U compinit
  compinit
fi
```